# How do I do proper SFINAE on inheriting constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do SFINAE on a constructor. I want to enable one overload for integers and one for everything else. I know I can just make a `base(int)` and `base(T)` constructor but I want to do it this way instead.

```
template <class T>
struct base
{
    template <class T1 = T>
    base(T1, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T1, int>::value>::type* = nullptr) {}

    template <class T1 = T>
    base(T1, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T1, int>::value>::type* = nullptr) {}
};
```

Then I make a main `Base` class that inherits the constructors:

```
template <class T>
struct Base : base<T>
{
    using base<T>::base;
};
```

But when I instantiate `Base` with any `T` I get these errors:

```
source_file.cpp:21:15: error: call to deleted constructor of 'Base<int>'
    Base<int> v(4);
              ^ ~
source_file.cpp:16:25: note: deleted constructor was inherited here
    using base<T>::base;
                        ^
source_file.cpp:7:5: note: constructor cannot be inherited
    base(T1, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T1, int>::value>::type* = nullptr) {}
    ^
```

When I instantiate `base` directly it works without a problem. Why can't the constructor be inherited when I am doing SFINAE? Without the second constructor overload everything works fine.

Comment: The error messages refer to `base_impl` but your source doesn't provide it - just a copy and paste issue? (i.e. is `base` named `base_impl` in your actual code?)

Comment: @sfjac I just changed names slightly. `base` is actually `base_impl`.

Comment: Inheriting constructors [break really badly with SFINAE using default arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25657097/2756719). Just...don't do it.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. That sucks because I think for my situation they're needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructor inheritance failure with boost::multiprecision::mpz\_int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912280/constructor-inheritance-failure-with-boostmultiprecisionmpz-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid this problem altogether in the example program by defining only the generic constructor in `base` and providing a specialization for `base<int>` ([DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f20511b0a17bc6c)):

```
template <class T>
struct base
{
    base(T) { std::cout << "generic constructor\n"; }
};

template <>
base<int>::base(int) { std::cout << "int specialization\n"; }
```

or use tag dispatching instead of SFINAE ([DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bea17e6569cc583)):

```
template <class T>
class base
{
    base(std::true_type, int) { std::cout << "int specialization\n"; }
    base(std::false_type, T) { std::cout << "generic constructor\n"; }

public:
    base(T t) : base(std::is_same<int, T>{}, std::move(t)) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the parameter list of a constructor, the entire *template* parameter list is always inherited including default template arguments. Put the SFINAE there:

```
template <class T>
struct base
{
    template <class T1 = T,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T1, int>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    base(T1) {}

    template <class T1 = T,
      typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T1, int>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    base(T1) {}
};
```

This works in Clang and GCC, in `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++1z` modes. (Only recent versions tested, 3.6 and 5.1, respectively.)